# Creating activation code in input

Tags: php, html, input, activation

How can I create a  textfield in which the user would be redirected to specific page, only after he has entered the specific number created by me? And if the code is invalid he would get a red border around that tab and some kind of message ("not successful" or something like this)?

Could that be done with php?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Activation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="activation">
        <label class="label">Please enter activation code to continue:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="activation"/>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Activate</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I were to do this using barebones HTML/JS/PHP with no framework involved, I would have created a handler for the onSubmit event on the Activate button and fire an Ajax call on the event which submits the form data to the server and expects a response from PHP. Based on that response I would redirect the user to another page or load an appropriate error div to show the relevant error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this line as well in your form

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Activation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="activation">
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <label class="label">Please enter activation code to continue:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="activation"/>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Activate</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['activation'])){
    $activation=$_POST['activation'];
    //Lets the code is 4
    if($activation==4)
    {
        //Your file name(lets say you want to redirect to index.html)
        header('Location:index.html');
    }
 else {
        echo "<div id='divname'>And the the code of div goes here.</div>";    
    }

}
```

Comment: It worked, also is there a way to load a specific <div> or just something in the same window the activation form is in? Since in this case it show the text in another page.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your button action onClick("someaction.php"). Than you just read data with $_post in PHP and do what you want